# After power outages the same type of light bulbs don't work anymore

Tags: electrical

Wind knocked out electricity multiple times today and  my light bulbs were very dim or not working and I replaced with a new same bulb but does not work even though the old one that's dim still works just very dim and my central heater motor blower went out. Is this normal?

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?  Are these incandescent, LED, or CFL bulbs?

Comment: Sounds like a broken neutral wire or damaged pole transformer. If some lights in the house are *much* brighter than normal, you've got an open neutral issue which can cause appliance damage or fire.

Answer (score 7):

This is **NOT** normal. There are two likely possibilities that I can think of:

- **Surges and other transient problems**
  A series of surges and other transient problems related to the power going off/on quickly could "zap" many devices and possibly leave some fixtures. However, light bulbs are a very good indicator because most consumer light bulbs, whether incandescent, compact fluorescent or LED, are self-contained so that switches wiring & fixtures are passive elements. In other words, if you replace a bulb and it *still* has problems then a surge that zapped the original bulb is **not** the problem because a new bulb would not be affected.
- **Lost pole or neutral**
  In the US, power comes in to most houses with 2 hot wires (called phases or more properly poles) and 1 neutral wire. If all of those wires are disconnected, you have no power. If just one of those wires is disconnected you can end up with all kinds of strange **and dangerous** problems. A simple test is to use a multimeter to check the voltage between the hot wire in a receptacle and the neutral wire. All receptacles should show the same voltage - nominally 120V, though anywhere from 110 V to 125 V is OK. But if some receptacles show significantly lower (== dim bulbs) and some show significantly higher (== things get "zapped") then you have a big problem. **THIS IS A PROBLEM FOR THE UTILITY COMPANY TO FIX.**

#### Recommendation: Call your local electric utility and tell them that following the high winds and intermittent outages, you now appear to have a partial power outage, specifically that you may have **LOST NEUTRAL**.

The electric utility should treat this as a serious problem and send someone out to check & fix it. Since the problem followed strong winds, that is another indication that it is a utility problem rather than a problem with the wiring inside your house.

If my hunch is correct, using **any** electric devices is potentially risky until this is resolved. If you are using your computer and it seems to work OK, that is because many computers are now designed for international operation on anywhere from 90 V to 240 V, so they are able to handle the differences. But that doesn't mean you don't have a serious problem affecting all electric devices in your house.

Comment: More properly phases: poles are for DC, phases are for AC, at least in Italian (battery has positive and negative pholes, Transformer has R S T phases)

Comment: @DDS True, except that as numerous people have noted in other questions, residential service is typically served by a single 240V phase, split into 2 120V sections. While the overall service by the utility is 3-phase, only big buildings actually get 3 phases. *I think...*

Comment: Actually it does not, 'low-voltage' service is delivered as 230/400V so at home you get 230V over 2 wires or 400V over 4 wires if you require more than 10kW service.